# Equivalent of PyInstaller for R scripts?

Tags: r, pyinstaller, exe, inno-setup

My team is supposed to create an executable file (EXE) from an original code written in R. In Python, PyIntaller offers the possibility to make a stand-alone application from a .py script. Is there any equivalent of that in R?

Let's say I want to convert this `hello.R` to `hello.exe`.

```
#hello.R
hello <- function(yourName = "John") {
  cat("Hello there", yourName, "\n")
}
```

The user should call the function `hello.R` into CMD and pass an argument (let's say `hello.exe Brad` so the prompt will be "Hello there Brad").

I tried RInno library in R but that didn't work (their examples in the documentation are not working properly because of the old R versions not being available). I'm also exploring Inno Setup but I don't exactly figure out what has to be inside that  `.iss` file and if Inno can create a portable application or it's just compiling a code to be installed as a program (which I don't need in my example).

Comment: Nothing recent. There's `Rinno`, not updated since 2018 (and self-labeled as "orphaned"). You might try https://medium.com/@mcodrescu/how-to-create-a-desktop-application-with-r-shiny-chromium-and-inno-setup-b47cee8ab788 or https://github.com/derryleng/Shiny_Desktop_App, never used them.